# Script is not executed in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to draw rectangle with one diagonal line using canvas and script. But, unfortunately rectangle alone is getting displayed in my browser. It looks like the script is not executed.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';

class Graphics extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div id="canvas">
            Draw a diagonal Line in Rectangular

            <canvas id="myCanvas" className="canvas-style" width="200" height="100">
</canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
</script>
</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Graphics;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="canvas">
          Draw a diagonal Line in Rectangular
        <canvas
          id="myCanvas"
          className="canvas-style"
          width="200"
          height="100" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write your script tag inside `componentDidMount()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
class Graphics extends Component{
 componentDidMount(){
   var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.moveTo(0,0);
   ctx.lineTo(200,100);
   ctx.stroke();
  }
    render(){
        return(
            <div id="canvas">
            Draw a diagonal Line in Rectangular

            <canvas id="myCanvas" className="canvas-style" width="200" height="100">
            </canvas>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Graphics;
```